# Error 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 268: invalid start byte when read file csv

Tags: python, django

I have error when read file csv
my code

```
class ImportExcel(APIView):
    permission_classes = []
    def post(self, request):
        final = []
        import openpyxl
        file = request.FILES['file']
        print(file)
        data = file.read().decode("utf-8")
        line = data.split('\n')
        for item in line:
            field = line.split(',')
            data_dict = {}
            data_dict['name'] = field[0]
            data_dict['number'] = field[1]
            final.append(data_dict)
        return Response(final)
```

and my error

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 268: invalid start byte
```

Please to help me fix this thank all

Comment: use Google to check what char has code `'0x96'` - it can be char in different encoding - `Latin1`, `Window-1250`, `ISO-8859-1`, etc. So you will have to use it in `decode(...)`

Comment: Which python version you are using?

Comment: Thank you! i fixed (change 'utf-8' to 'ISO-8859-1')